# Unwanted ui-resizer between North layoutUnit and Center layoutUnit

Tags: css, layout, primefaces

How can remove that `ui-resizer` between the top layoutUnit and the center one?
I don't why it appears, I have tried using closable, resizable, but it won't work.

This is my index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<h:head>
    <title>GG Well Trade</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-autocomplete input {
            width: 74%;
        }

        .ui-autocomplete {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .ui-widget {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .ui-layout-unit {
            border: none;
        }

        .ui-layout-unit .ui-layout-unit-content {
            border: none;
            overflow: hidden !important;
        }

        hr {
            border: none;
            height: 1px;
            color: lightgray;
            background-color: lightgray;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration:none;
        }
    </style>

    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" style="text-align: center">
            <p:graphicImage library="img" name="about/LOGO.png"/>
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center">

            <p:layout>

                <h:form>
                    <p:layoutUnit position="north">
                    </p:layoutUnit>

                </h:form>



                <p:layoutUnit position="south" header="Credits">




                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>






</h:body>
</html>
```

Every layoutUnit isn't resizable but you can resize the North one, why?

Comment: I have edited the first post

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug but the `<h:form>` that is wrapping the `<p:layoutUnit position="north">` generates a `ui-resizer`  in the HTML page

Comment: It is certainly not a bug since it is 'wrong' usage of you. There should not be any tags between the layout and the layout-unit (or surrounding the layout unit like in your case). It is at most an inconvenience. Put the form inside the layout-unit.